# Change button text of a cloned element

Tags: javascript

Making an food ordering app. There is a first table with all items you can choose. Each item have a button. On this button click it clones the line and put it in a second table containing your chosen items. I would like to change the text content of the button when the element go to the second table. Like "+" in the first table become "-" in the second table (to next delete the item of the second table on "-" click)

HTML

```
<h1>CHOOSE</h1>

<table id="starters">
      <tr>
        <th>PRODUCT</th>
        <th>PRICE</th>
        <th>ADD TO CART</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cherry</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td><button class="item_button">+</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Peach</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td><button class="item_button">+</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Strawberry</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td><button class="item_button">+</button></td>
      </tr>

</table>

<h1>YOUR CHOICE</h1>   

<table id="products_cart">

</table>
```

JS

```
let basket = document.getElementById("products_cart")

let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.item_button');

for (button of buttons) {
 button.addEventListener('click', cloneLine);
}

function cloneLine(e) {
 let td = e.target.parentNode;
 let tr = td.parentNode;
 let clone = tr.cloneNode(true);
 basket.appendChild(clone);
}
```

I tried different things like to get (querySelectorAll) the buttons and change their innerHTML (or textContent or innerText) with no success. I also tried to create another button and to replace the former by the newer.

Comment: It's not clear where or when you want to change the text. In `cloneLine`, `clone` contains the row, so you could just do `clone.querySelector('.item_button').textContent = "-";`...

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. In `cloneLine` was the best. Thanks for our help it's running.